# How to change the color of QWizard or QWizardPage background?

Tags: c++, qt

in Qt it is possible to specify the background color of QWizard Page?

Using `setColor` in  `QPallete::Base` of the `qApp` of, if using a generic window, the background changes to the correct color.

However, if using a `QWizard` or `QWizardPage`, the background is set to white.
Using

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: #000000; background-color: #2a82da; border: 1px solid white; } ");
```

the color changes, but a lot of other elements also change to that color(all the widgets).

How is it possible to specify the color change to `QWizard` or `QWizardPage`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting `QWizard` or `QWizardPage` into the selector in place of `QWidget`?

Comment: Using `qApp->setStyleSheet`? Yes but this way it gets white as usual. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, this seems to work:

```
QWizard wizard;
wizard.setStyleSheet("background-color:#E8E8E8");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is the solution.

Assume I have a child class of `QWizard`:

```
this->setObjectName("wizard");   
this->setStyleSheet("#wizard { background : #f4f7f9; ");
```

changes the wizard background color without affecting other elements.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5 when you change background color.

- `QWizard` - `QPalette::Window` - place near bottom buttons
- `qDebug()<< QWizardPage->backgroundRole();` get us `QPalette::ColorRole(Window).`
  But it's not true, real value is `QPalette::Base`

Code:

`QPalette` `bgpal`

```
bgpal.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
setPalette(bgpal);
this->setAutoFillBackground(true);

`this->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::YourPalette)`; don't recommend to use, on olds Qt it has a bug.
```

P.S.
Ye, it has the same role as lineEdit background and if you set to QLE border 0 you will get:

[image]